# Speed of light - quantum unobserved

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light, double-slit-experiment, observers

Although I am sorry that I don't understand it very well at all, I understand that the slit-lamp experiment is affected by whether it is being observed. How do we know that the speed of light is not instantaneous when it's not being observed?

Comment: Why would light's speed be a quantum variable?

Comment: I'm asking why not. Although I have to read up on what a quantum variable is

Answer (score 0):

Light isn't a particle, its an electromagnetic wave with a speed given by Maxwell's equation and always travels in that speed: $$c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0 \mu_0 }}$$But this is a classical argument, right, but in QED if I remember correctly we use the same propagation given by Maxwell's equations. Furthermore, every experiment ever done to calculate the speed of light always gave the same result. There is no way that light travels from one place to the other instantly, it would violate special relativity...

So there are a lot of reasons why we believe $c$ is constant. I hope it helped convincing you.